# Dynamically switch components and call the function save of active component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

to switch from one component to another component , I use `<component>` element from vue which is used to render the components dynamically by adding :is special attribute.        `<component :is="selected"></component>` 
 
my code :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <component :is="selected"></component>
    <b-button @click="nextComponent">next</b-button>
  </div>
</template>
```

there are two new components called Home and Contact inside our components folder.

```
<script>
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      tabs: ["Home", "Contact"],
      selected: "Home"
    };
  },
  components: {
    Home,
    Contact
  },
  nextComponent () {
     let index = 0
     let nameComponent = this.tabs[index]
     const total = this.tabs.length
     if (index >= total) {
       index = 0
       this.selected = nameComponent
       } else {
        index++
        this.selected = nameComponent
       }
     this.$emit('save')
  }
};
</script>
```

the issue is how to call the function `save` of active component . I mean if ie `selected = Home` how to call `save` in Home.Vue ?

There are these functions in my components

```
mounted () {
    this.$on('save', this.save)
},
methods: {
save () {
   console.log('to check if it works')
 }
}
```

but it doesn't works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this, you are only registering the `save` function to be triggered on the ***'save'*** event. You are not executing/calling the function in `mounted` hook.

```
mounted () {
    this.$on('save', this.save)
},
```

To call it on the initial mount, just execute the function in `mounted` too.

Like so:

```
mounted () {
    this.$on('save', this.save);
    this.save() // <-- calling the function when component mounts

},
```

Now this function `save` will be called on initial mount and whenever it gets the ***'save'*** event.